# How can I query files uploaed by other users?

Tags: soap, query, user, document

I tried to sample code from the [Quick Start Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_erd_content.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_erd_content.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

And I want to get file information which is uploaded by any users in my Salesforce.

What I tried query is

```
SELECT name, folderid, authorid, developername FROM Document
```

But only get information about files that I uploaded.

I am the administrator, so I think there was no authority problem.

Tell anything I can try other ways.

Also, I want to download that files.

Let me know whether this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ALL ROWS at the end of SOQL like this:

```
[SELECT name, folderid, authorid, developername FROM Document ALL ROWS];
```

If you are using this soql in apex code, make sure it should be set as **without sharing**